# Ruby on Rails - Calculate sum amounts with categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I'm having diffculties calculating the proper amount per parent category.

- Product belongs to a category.
- A category can belong to a parent category

I want to calculate what the total amount per parent category is for all products, even if it belongs to a child of the parent category.

Current code:

```
      result = Product
      .joins(category: [:parent_category])
      .where(created_at: Time.current.beginning_of_year..Time.current.end_of_year)
      .group("products.category_id, product_categories.parent_id, parent_categories_product_categories.name")
      .pluck("products.category_id, product_categories.parent_id, parent_categories_product_categories.name, SUM(amount)")
```

Example:

Outdoor - $10.000
Indoor - $15.000

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried .select instead of .pluck at the end?

Comment: please, share the real error message